# SQLite: equivalent of ON DELETE RESTRICT for "soft deletions" (table field becomes non-NULL)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

As usual, I'm implementing a "soft deletion" pattern (on an SQLite database): never actually delete anything on-disk, just hide it in the application.

My `master` table looks like:

- `id` (INT)
- `deleted` (NULL or TEXT) ie. NULL or ISO date/time of the deletion
- ...

When I want to "delete" a record I actually just set its `deleted` field to the current date/time.

I also have another table `references` that stores relationships:

- `id` (INT, FOREIGN KEY master.id ON DELETE RESTRICT)
- `ref` (INT, FOREIGN KEY master.id ON DELETE RESTRICT)

Meaning, `id` has a reference to `ref` so you can't have it dangling.

Obviously, thanks to FOREIGN KEYs you can't actually SQL `DELETE` a record in the `master` table if it is referenced by any `references.id/ref`, the engine enforces that. But I'd like to extend this check, if possible, to the "soft deletion".

**In other words, I'd like to forbid any SQL `UPDATE` of the `master.deleted` field from NULL to non-NULL if and only if the `master.id` is listed in `references.id/ref`.**

Until now, enforcing this at the application level was enough for my needs, but on this project I really need "belt and suspenders" so the database layer should really enforce it too. And I have no clue how to begin unraveling it.

Comment: Have you tried a trigger? https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: I have to admit, I never used triggers. Actually I barely know they exist, which means I have no idea what they can really do. But after a cursory glance this looks like a trail. :)

Comment: @Serg Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, triggers did the trick. Actually it took me much longer understanding how they work than writing the trigger itself, which worked on first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Serg, **triggers** solve this problem.

In addition to the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), this [tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/) greatly helped me make sense of it.

Here's what I came up with. This is my first try so it can probably be enhanced performance-wise, but the functionality is here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER master_soft_delete
  BEFORE UPDATE OF deleted
  ON master
  WHEN (OLD.deleted IS NULL) AND (NEW.deleted IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM references AS r
                  WHERE (id = NEW.id) OR (ref = NEW.id) LIMIT 1)
           THEN
        RAISE(ABORT, 'master.id in references, aborting soft deletion')
  END;
END;
```